# Normalization of a sequence of images via ImageMagick or other means?

Tags: image, image-processing, ffmpeg, imagemagick, video-processing

I have a series of images that change relatively little during the day, but suffer from severe over and underexposure sometimes.  There's nothing I can do in the way of fixing the loss of details, however I want to make it so that one from to the next is not so jolting.  In other words, I'd like to normalize brightness / color levels the sequence of images so that it feels more consistent from one from to the next.  Ultimately this sequence is being encoded to a video and therefore why this is important to me.

How can I normalize these values for a series of a few hundred frames via ImageMagick or some other means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ImageMagick command-line's [-equalize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=quc2uajippmh7ab07lp92csoo4#equalize) option, that should do the trick. This will only adjust the current image to use its full color range properly.

If you want one image to match it's histogram and/or saturation to another, use [this ImageMagick script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/histmatch/index.php).

Comment: Can you give me some example in terms of how I could run this operation across a sequence of images so that the function will have the appropriate context for equalizing all images appropriately?

Comment: If you want one to match another, see my modified answer above.